# Tier 5 (Youth Mobility Visa) - Age

Tags: visas, uk

With the [Tier 5 Youth Mobility Visa](https://www.gov.uk/tier-5-youth-mobility), if I turn 31 next week, and pay for all the application today, once I get all my paperwork approved, will I be able to enter and re-enter the UK for the defined 2-year period of the Tier 5 Year Mobility Visa (as I will greater than 31 (32 and 33))?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You must be " under the age of 31 *on the date your application is made*." .
My emphasis

Guidance published here https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-visa-applications-under-tier-5-youth-mobility-scheme

Comment: So, despite being over 31, as long as I have the visa, I can enter the UK to work multiple time irrespective of my current age at the time? Would you be able to direct me to a document where it states so? Its just a very costly excercise...to apply for the visa and travel there

Comment: The document I linked to is the one to read. If the rule was "must be under 31 for the duration of the visa" then they would have said that instead. Actually, they would have said "under 29 on the date the application is made" if that was their intention.